# Formatting a Semantic MediaWiki query resulttable template with cell newlines

Tags: templates, mediawiki, tablelayout, semantic-mediawiki

I need a semantic query result table template where I can have both newline-delimited cell results for some columns and comma-delimited columns in the same table.

If I use the standard **format=broadtable**, for example, the result is separated by newlines inside the table cells for all columns:

```
{{#ask:[[Category:Items]]
|?Description
|?Models
|?Addons
|format=broadtable
}}
```

If I create a template, all I am able to accomplish is a comma-separated result:

```
<includeonly>
{| class="wikitable sortable"
 ! style="width: 30%;" | Page
 !! style="width: 30%;" | Description
 !! style="width: 20%;" | Models
 !! style="width: 20%;" | Addons
 |-
</includeonly>

{{#ask:[[Category:Items]]
|?Description
|?Models
|?Addons
|format=template
|template=QResTemplate
}}

<includeonly>
|}
</includeonly>
```

Here is the QResTemplate:

```
<includeonly>
 | {{{1}}} || {{{2}}} || {{{3}}} || {{{4}}}
 |-
</includeonly>
```

Every Item has multiple Models and Addons, so it is column 3 and 4 in the table that I need one of them to be comma-separated while the other is newline-separated.

If I add something after {{{3}}}, like a newline, it is added after the last Model on the table row, not after each Model as I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Extension:Arrays](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Arrays) to format your comma separated outputs as you want:

```
<includeonly><!--

       store arrays

 -->{{#arraydefine:models|{{{3}}}}}<!--
 -->{{#arraydefine:addons|{{{4}}}}}<!--

       print row

 -->
 | {{{1}}} || {{{2}}} || {{#arrayprint:models|<br/>}} || {{#arrayprint:addons|, }}
 |-
</includeonly>
```

First you store both lists as arrays. `arraydefine` assumes that your list is comma separated, unless you specify somthing else. Then you print your arrays again with `#arrayprint`, but this time you can decide how you want those values to be separated.

If you can't use commas (e.g. because some value contains a comma, you can add e.g. `sep=¤` to your ask query, and then do `{{#arraydefine:models|{{{3}}}|¤}}` to tell arraydefine that you are using a different separator.